# Pass a Range as a Function Parameter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am writing a function that needs to pass a specified range into it, but I keep getting an error whenever I call the function. Here's some example code--the code in the function is unimportant, as all I want to do is be able to use the passed in range for anything within.

**My Declaration:**

```
Sub exampleFunction (exampleRange as Range)

    exampleRange.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium

End Sub
```

But when I try to call the function with this code:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Sheet1.Range ("C2") 

exampleFunction (myRange) ' <-- This is what doesn't work
```

I get an error that says "Compile Error: Expected: =".

What do I need to do to pass in myRange correctly during the function call?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around `myRange` i.e.`exampleFunction myRange`

Comment: What if I have multiple parameters? How would I go about formatting it then?

Comment: Separate with a comma e.g. `exampleFunction myRange1, myRange2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exampleFunction (myRange)
```

should be

```
exampleFunction myRange
```

or for multiple arguments:

```
exampleFunction myRange, myString, myInt
```

You only use () when your method returns a value or when using the `Call` keyword.

If you wrap your argument in `()` - and you're not calling a Function or using Call - then VBA will first evaluate the argument *before passing it to your method* - you often don't want that.

You can see the impact of this evaluation in the Immediate window:

```
? typename( Range("A1") )    '>> "Range"

? typename( (Range("A1")) )  '>> "Double" (if A1 has a numeric value)
                             '   "String" (if A1 has a text value)
```

Comment: I think we answered simultaneously!

Comment: Ok. What if it is exampleFunction( num as integer, exampleRange as range)